# setup kerberos constrained delegation powershell

Tags: powershell, kerberos

I'm trying to add setup Kerberos delegation in Windows server 2012 R2 for a service account. Using the **Set-ADObject** command and the property **TrustedForDelegation** I can enable the radio button for "Trust this user for delegation to specified services only" but the option "Use any authentication protocol" is chosen by default.

I've already set the SPN's and can add the services to delegate using the property **msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo**, but I can't seem to force "Use Kerberos only".

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting only the msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo property using the Set-ADObject command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the **TrustedForDelegation** property should not be added manually. Just providing **msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo** followed by your SPN's will set up the kerberos delegation properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for a bunch of servers for VMM migration to work:

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=that1OU,DC=MyDomain,DC=com"
```

with a foreach to run the following:

```
Set-ADComputer -Identity $server.name -Add @{'msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo'=@("$ServiceName/$ObjectName","$AnotherServiceName/$ObjectName","$Servicename/$ObjectFQDN","$AnotherServiceName/$ObjectFQDN")}
```

Something like that.
You get the idea.